# Iframe - automaticly change height of the Iframe when the width of the window is changed

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an Iframe on my website with it's content flexible (I want this to work on mobile devices.)

The iFrame code is

```
<iframe src="projects/" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'></iframe>
```

This is also on the same website, so it loads and rezises perfectly.

This is the javascript the iframe calls:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe(obj) {
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }

    window.onresize = function(event) {
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

Now, the problem is that, I want it to change the height of the Iframe, every time the width of the browser changes. This dosen't work now. It works when I refresh the website in different width resolutions, but only then. I simply want the script to checked every time the width of the browser is changed.

How do I do that?

I appreciate all help I can get

**UPDATE**

Okay, I've changed my javascript code but it dosen't work, I think? (I'm very new to javascript)

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = function() {
        var obj = document.getElementById('iframer').document;
        alert('Changing the height!');

        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
        alert('Height set!');
</script>
```

The first alert shows but not the second. So there seems to be somthing wrong.

I appreciate all help I can get. :-)

Comment: `obj` isnt defined within the `window.onresize` function

Comment: Following up on Patrick's note, define `obj` outside of both both functions definitions.

Comment: Why aren't you calling the function?  Do you always copy/paste?